# Stopwatch inside of a timer not working in C#

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
if (!App.stopWatch.IsRunning) { App.stopWatch.Start(); }
Device.StartTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1), () =>
{
   if (App.stopWatch.IsRunning && App.stopWatch.Elapsed.Seconds >= 60)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Reducing Points");
      App.stopWatch.Restart();
   }
   return true;
});
```

I expect that every 60 seconds it would go into the if and write a message to the console.  But when I run in Debug mode, it never gets there and what's even more confusing to me is that the stopWatch elapsed time goes up to 60 and then resets. Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Seconds` property of the `TimeSpan` structure gets the seconds component of the time interval. The type is an `int` and the range of this value is from -59 to 59. If you had a `TimeSpan` of 59 seconds and you added one second to it then the `Seconds` property would become `0` and the `.Minutes` property becomes `1`.

If you want the total seconds represented by a `TimeSpan` then you need `TotalSeconds` (which is a `double` as it also represents the number of fractional seconds that have elapsed.